# Use a execute command once

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I understand commands but I am fairly new to the 1.13 changes.

I am trying to make an AFK system within vanilla Minecraft.

I want to use the /execute command to execute once. I want to detect when a scoreboard objective is a certain value and print

```
[Player] has gone AFK
```

in the chat only once. This is my command at the moment,

```
execute as @a[scores={afk=1..}] at @s run tellraw @a {"text":"","color":"red","extra":[{"selector":"@s"},{"text":" has gone AFK.","color":"yellow"}]}
```

It keeps printing until the scoreboard value is reset.

Comment: AFK is cheating. No worse than /give

Comment: I'm trying to make it for fun, all it does is put you into the air. Yes, that may be cheating. I'm just trying to have some fun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
1. /execute as @a[scores={afk=1..},tag=!afkMesaage] run tellraw @a <your message>
2. /tag add @a[scores={afk=1..}] afkMessage
3. /tag remove @a[scores={afk=0}] afkMessage
```

Command blocks:

1. Repeating, Always active
2. Chain, Always active
3. Chain, Always active

Comment: Cannot test it now, but should work

Comment: any way to make this work with a teleporting command system? say, if someone wanted to make a way so that players were facing a specific direction at a specific time?

Comment: You want to teleport players somewhere when they are looking in some direction?

Comment: Maybe /execute as @a[x_rotation=?,y=rotation=?] at @s run tp x y z

Comment: other way around, actually. i want to force them to look in a direction at a specific location, but only once so they aren't constantly forced to. (ie. i want to make a pseudo spawn point where they're looking in a direction i need)

Comment: Make some pressure plate and then /execute as @p at @s run tp ~ ~ ~ xrotation yrotation

Comment: i'd agree, but i was pointed here as a way to do that without the use of pressure plates (for the sake of conserving looks that i wanted to have for the spawn).

Comment: Tp everyone who dont have teleported tag and then add that tag to everyone